# Facet_wrap individual-level data by time and treatment status (ggplot2)

Tags: ggplot2, graph, tidyverse, facet

I have a survey data structured as follows:
The survey tracks the self-reported "mood" for individuals with depression problems every 3 days between Sept 3rd through Sept 12th. All observations are exposed to treatment on Sept 9th, 2012. The survey contains 400 unique observations, but some observations drop out after the treatment.

Here is a data example:

```
individual  date            mood         treatment 
McCfly      2012-09-03.     sad           pre
McCfly      2012-09-06.     sad            pre
McCfly      2012-09-09.     happy          post 
McCfly      2012-09-12.     happy          post
Cartman   2012-09-03.       sad           pre
Cartman  2012-09-06.        sad            pre
Cartman  2012-09-09.        sad            post 
Cartman    2012-09-12.      neutral        post
Mackey   2012-09-03.       sad            pre
Mackey  2012-09-06.        sad             pre
Mackey  2012-09-09.        happy             post
```

I want to visualize each person's self-reported happiness throughout 1) time and 2) treatment status, but I am not sure if a [facet_graph](https://ggplot2-book.org/facet.html) is the best option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you change the question tittle as it does not seem to reflect the actual question you are asking in the post.

Now some alternatives:

- You could certainly use facets to display individuals, but depending on how many individuals you want to display this might not be feasible.
- You could also use a line graph with a discrete y-axis for this purpose. Here's a putative implementation:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(
  individual = c("John","John","John","John",
                 "Jerry","Jerry","Jerry","Jerry",
                 "Monica","Monica","Monica","Monica",
                 "Tom","Tom","Tom","Tom"), 
  date = rep(seq(1:4),4),
  mood = c("sad","sad","happy","happy",
           "sad","neutral","happy","neutral",
           "sad","sad","happy","happy",
           "sad","sad","neutral","neutral"),
  neutral = c("pre","pre","post","post",
              "pre","pre","post","post",
              "pre","pre","post","post",
              "pre","pre","post","post"))

data$mood <- factor(data$mood, levels = c("sad","neutral","happy"))

ggplot(data = data) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 1, xmax = 2.5, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), 
            alpha = 0.1, fill = "antiquewhite") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 2.5, xmax = 4, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), 
            alpha = 0.1, fill = "lavender") +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x=date,y=mood,
                          group=individual,
                          color=individual,lty=individual)) +
  annotate("text", x=1.7, y=3.3, label= "Pre-treatment") + 
  annotate("text", x=3.3, y=3.3, label= "Post-treatment") + 
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: The solution works well, but is it scalable when you have more observations, especially if different individuals have different dates, perhaps there is a loop for this?

Comment: - Yeah, I don't think you could incorporate individuals with different dates in this plot scheme, unless you do it as I did and bundle dates as 1,2,3,4. This could be fine as it seems that pre- and post-treatment are really what matters for interpretation.
- If you want granularity, one facet for each individual might really be what you are looking for.